# Is there a Captcha FAQ which explains why it's used when you're logged in?

Tags: discussion, captcha

Is there a Captcha FAQ which explains why it's used when you're logged in?
I understand, in general, they are used to stop comment spam bots but when you're logged in, it seems there are other considerations? Like slowing down users?

Comment: The exact implementation details of the spam counter-measures are not public.  For very obvious reasons.  Asking for details is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

The only purpose is to stop bots; there's normal rate limiting used to stop you from manually doing things too fast. For example, if you vote on comments too fast you'll get:

[image: You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.]

You won't get a captcha for that; it just tracks when you last submitted a vote and stops you completely from submitting another one too fast

Comment: I edited a question twice in a short time and got a captcha. If the site thinks I am a bot, I, as a bot developer, would be smarter than that and delay the actions and randomize the delays.

Comment: @Tony Thus slowing down the bot -- sounds like a win for everyone. The goal is to prevent bots from causing mass destruction before a mod notices and stops them

Comment: @Tony: We have complained before about the captcha, no interest in improving the edit timer.

Comment: @Changeling Whether or not the catpcha timer is right is a totally separate issue, and I agree that it's too short, I used to hit it all the time

Comment: It's a related issue.